# Docker Multi Stage Build access Test Reports in Jenkins when Tests Fail

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, pytest, docker-multi-stage-build

I am doing a multi stage build in docker to separate the app from testing. Now at some point in my Dockerfile I run:

```
RUN pytest --junit=test-reports/junit.xml
```

In my Jenkinsfile respectivly I do:

```
def app = docker.build("app:${BUILD_NUMBER}", "--target test .")
app.inside {
  sh "cp -r /app/test-reports test-reports"
}

junit 'test-reports/junit.xml'
```

Now if my test fail, the build fails which is good. But the rest of the stage is not executed, i.e. I dont have access to the test-reports folder. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar task by using always block after build stage.
Please check if below code can help.

```sh
always{
    script{
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
        docker create -it --name test_report app:${BUILD_NUMBER} /bin/bash
        docker cp test_report:/app/test-reports ./test-reports
        docker rm -f test_report
        '''
    }

    junit 'test-reports/junit.xml'
}
```